# How to download YouTube videos at 1080p resolution?

Tags: python, youtube-api, web-crawler

I have tried the 3 following programs to download YouTube videos at 1080p resolution, but can only download 720p.

https://github.com/nficano/pytube

https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl

How can I download 1080p video by a script, so that I can then merge it with a
audio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you read that those all only do 720. That last link can do 1080p. This command will grab 1080 if it can, but fall back to the next highest resolution.

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]+bestaudio/best[height<=1080]' URL
```

Just video

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=1080]' URL
```

Comment: wow. your advice works well. Maybe My poor English make that only do 720, lol. Really thanks, Cricket !

Comment: I didn't try the others, but I'm sure they can also do the same because the YouTube API should let them