# How to download 1080p mp4 YouTube video using youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to download mp4 1080p videos from YouTube. I have tried this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P URL="Enter YouTube video URL: "
ECHO.
youtube-dl.exe -f mp4 ("bestvideo[width>=1920]"/bestvideo)+bestaudio/best -o %userprofile%/Downloads/YouTubeDL/%%(title)s_[YouTubeID=%%(id)s].%%(ext)s %URL%
ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

It's returning errors. While researching, I bumped into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623279/how-to-download-youtube-1080p-by-program) but it doesn't answer how I can **download mp4** only videos.

The code below works but often downloads webm files.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P URL="Enter YouTube video URL: "
ECHO.
youtube-dl.exe -f ("bestvideo[width>=1920]"/bestvideo)+bestaudio/best -o %userprofile%/Downloads/YouTubeDL/%%(title)s_[YouTubeID=%%(id)s].%%(ext)s %URL%
ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following.

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio --merge-output-format mp4 https://youtube...
```

Comment: This won't work most of the time because if webm file is downloaded, it won't merge as discussed here: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/16819

Comment: @SakibArifin this issue was fixed already in the new versions. Btw i tried it and it did save it as a .mp4.

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this solve your issue, or did it not help you at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my issue. I posted pictures of what happened after I tried your solution in my forum: https://ict.sakibarifin.com/d/43-youtube-dl-fails-to-merge-mp4-output-with-merge-output-format-mp4-parameter

Comment: this might happen because ffmpeg is not updated. Try updating it.

Comment: Ok, I will try with the latest ffmpeg.